# mysql query date render yesterday records instead today

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT sum(AfterDiscount) AS
AfterDiscount,DATE_FORMAT(UpdateDate,'%d-%m-%Y')
as UpdateDate FROM tblsale where
date_format(UpdateDate,'Y-m-d')=date_format(now(),'Y-m-d')
AND BillType='s'
```

This  query render the 28 th records instead today ,

i want to render records by today dates

Problem fixed,

```
SELECT sum(AfterDiscount) AS
AfterDiscount,DATE_FORMAT(UpdateDate,'%d-%m-%Y')
as UpdateDate FROM tblsale where
date_format(UpdateDate,'%Y-%m-%d')=date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d') AND BillType='s'
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not compare `WHERE DATE(UpdateDate)=CURRENT_DATE()` ? Why go the trouble of formatting?

**EDIT**

Further functions found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date